# Need help to make [create-react-app] to use Aync - Await (transform-async-to-generator)!

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I am new to [create-react-app] and I would like to find out how can I add : ["transform-async-to-generator"] to this build process? In regular cases I would add it in .babelrc, but does not look to work* with [create-react-app].

*By "does not look to work" - I see the following error.

```
Syntax error: ../web/src/App.js: Unexpected token, expected ( (17:13)

  15 |   }
  16 |
> 17 |   test = async () => {
     |              ^
  18 |     let x = await this.resolveAfter2Seconds();
  19 |     try{}
  20 |     catch(exception){
```

And is any way to extend [create-react-app], without modifying the package itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not with async functions. You should rewrite your code the next way:

```
// ...

test = async () => {
  let x = await this.resolveAfter2Seconds();
  // ...
}
```

or

```
// ...
async test(){
  let x = await this.resolveAfter2Seconds();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: oh! sorry for coping the wrong code.. I was missing: babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator and babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions as @imcvampire mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You should add 2 plugins to babel: `babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator` and `babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions`